# Simple maths with javascript not changing fields in form

Tags: javascript

I can't get this part of my form to work. It is a two stage form. The second part is the same and it is working fine, it is just not as long

```
function calcTotal1()
        {
            var qty1, qty2, qty3, qty4, qty5, qty6, qty7, qty8, qty9, qty10, qty11, qty12, qty13;
            var ocost1, ocost2, ocost3, ocost4, ocost5, ocost6, ocost7, ocost8, ocost9, ocost10, ocost11, ocost12, ocost13;
            var otot1, otot2, otot3, otot4, otot5, otot6, otot7, otot8, otot9, otot10, otot11, otot12, otot13;
            var oSubTot6, oSubTot9;
            var oGrandTot;

            qty1 = document.orderform.sWorkbook8qty.value * 1.00;
            qty2 = document.orderform.sAnswerbook8qty.value * 1.00;
            qty3 = document.orderform.sWorkbook9qty.value * 1.00;
            qty4 = document.orderform.sAnswerbook9qty.value * 1.00;
            qty5 = document.orderform.sWorkbook10qty.value * 1.00;
            qty6 = document.orderform.sAnswerbook10qty.value * 1.00;
            qty7 = document.orderform.sStudentAnswerbook10qty.value * 1.00;
            qty8 = document.orderform.sWorkbook11qty.value * 1.00;
            qty9 = document.orderform.sAnswerbook11qty.value * 1.00;
            qty10 = document.orderform.sStudentAnswerbook11qty.value * 1.00;
            qty11 = document.orderform.sWorkbook12qty.value * 1.00;
            qty12 = document.orderform.sAnswerbook12qty.value * 1.00;
            qty13 = document.orderform.sStudentAnswerbook12qty.value * 1.00;


            ocost1 = document.orderform.sWorkbook8cost.value * 1.00;
            ocost2 = document.orderform.sAnswerbook8cost.value * 1.00;
            ocost3 = document.orderform.sWorkbook9cost.value * 1.00;
            ocost4 = document.orderform.sAnswerbook9cost.value * 1.00;
            ocost5 = document.orderform.sWorkbook10cost.value * 1.00;
            ocost6 = document.orderform.sAnswerbook10cost.value * 1.00;
            ocost7 = document.orderform.sStudentAnswerbook10cost.value * 1.00;
            ocost8 = document.orderform.sWorkbook11cost.value * 1.00;
            ocost9 = document.orderform.sAnswerbook11cost.value * 1.00;
            ocost10 = document.orderform.sStudentAnswerbook11cost.value * 1.00;
            ocost11 = document.orderform.sWorkbook12hgcost.value * 1.00;
            ocost12 = document.orderform.sAnswerbook12hgcost.value * 1.00;
            ocost13 = document.orderform.sStudentAnswerbook12hgcost.value * 1.00;


            otot1 = (eval(ocost1 * qty1)) * 1.00;
            otot2 = (eval(ocost2 * qty2)) * 1.00;
            otot3 = (eval(ocost3 * qty3)) * 1.00;
            otot4 = (eval(ocost4 * qty4)) * 1.00;
            otot5 = (eval(ocost5 * qty5)) * 1.00;
            otot6 = (eval(ocost6 * qty6)) * 1.00;
            otot7 = (eval(ocost7 * qty7)) * 1.00;
            otot8 = (eval(ocost8 * qty8)) * 1.00;
            otot9 = (eval(ocost9 * qty9)) * 1.00;
            otot10 = (eval(ocost10 * qty10)) * 1.00;
            otot11 = (eval(ocost11 * qty11)) * 1.00;
            otot12 = (eval(ocost12 * qty12)) * 1.00;
            otot13 = (eval(ocost13 * qty13)) * 1.00;

            document.orderform.sWorkbook8ttl.value = otot1;
            document.orderform.sAnswerbook8ttl.value = otot2;
            document.orderform.sWorkbook9ttl.value = otot3;
            document.orderform.sAnswerbook9ttl.value = otot4;
            document.orderform.sWorkbook10ttl.value = otot5;
            document.orderform.sAnswerbook10ttl.value = otot6;
            document.orderform.sStudentAnswerbook10ttl.value = otot7;
            document.orderform.sWorkbook11ttl.value = otot8;
            document.orderform.sAnswerbook11ttl.value = otot9;
            document.orderform.sStudentAnswerbook11ttl.value = otot10;
            document.orderform.sWorkbook12hgttl.value = otot11;
            document.orderform.sAnswerbook12hgttl.value = otot12;
            document.orderform.sStudentAnswerbook12hgttl.value = otot13;


            oSubTot6 = (oTot1 + oTot2) + (oTot3 + oTot4) + (oTot5 + oTot6) + (oTot7 + oTot8) + (oTot9 + oTot10) + (oTot11 + oTot12 + oTot13); 

            document.orderform.sSubtotal1.value = oSubTot6

            document.orderform.sGrandTotal.value = oSubTot6;
            }
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying a bunch of things by `1`? Why are you using `eval` on the result of a multiplication? And why are you multiplying those results by 1? And can you post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), please?

Comment: What does it do? What's not working? Did you try to debug it? And more importantly, *why are you using `eval` like that?*

Comment: Where did you learn to code like that? I'd start with a blank page.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? And why do you use `eval` to execute a multiplication?

Comment: @Sirko: It's even worse than that... The multiplication is done first, then the result is implicitly converted into a string and fed to the `eval` method, which only converts it back to a number.

Comment: You may want to go back a couple chapters in the textbook and re-read them.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what's not working, but just rewriting the code might help:

- Put the names in an array.
- Loop through the names and calculate the total for each pair of fields.
- Use `parseInt` and `parseFloat` to convert the strings to numbers, not `* 1.00`.
- Your use of `eval` is pointless, it's not needed at all.

Example:

```
var names = [
  'sWorkbook8','sAnswerbook8','sWorkbook9','sAnswerbook9',
  'sWorkbook10','sAnswerbook10','sStudentAnswerbook10',
  'sWorkbook11','sAnswerbook11','sStudentAnswerbook11',
  'sWorkbook12','sAnswerbook12','sStudentAnswerbook12'
];

var grand = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  var qty = parseInt(document.orderform[name[i] + 'qty'].value, 10);
  var cost = parseFloat(document.orderform[name[i] + 'cost'].value);
  var total = qty * cost;
  document.orderform[name[i] + 'ttl'].value = total;
  grand += total;
}

document.orderform.sSubtotal1.value = grand;
document.orderform.sGrandTotal.value = grand;
```

Comment: thank you, i will try this. It is just strange that one part is working with the code i am using. here is a link to the site that it is for http://www.hsecc.co.za/order.asp?sPage=Workbooks%20and%20Answer%20Books  yo can see for yourself.

Comment: @Aquizile: The field is named `sWorkbook12hgqty`, not `sWorkbook12qty`.

Comment: Heh, I figured the issue was something like that. +1 for refactoring that code.

Comment: Thank you Guffa for going through my script. I have got both sides working now, just two more bugs. I changed the field names -- couldn't believe it. Your script doesn't seem to work. Was just wondering about document.orderform[name[i]... is the first '[' a substitute for '.'?

Comment: @Aquizile: You need to check what error message you get when it doesn't work, otherwise it's very hard to spot an error in the code. You use `[]` to access properties using a string. Using `obj['asdf']` is the same as `obj.asdf`.

Comment: Thank you! There was no error messages. After changing the qty nothing happened. (Just have one more bug now. The grandtotal is not adding the 2 subtotals.. 2+2 should = 4 but it gives me 22.)

Comment: @Aquizile: Aha, you are adding strings. `'2'+'2'` is `'22'` while `2+2` is `4`.

Comment: Gaffa thank you for all the help. I'm sure I uderstand things better now. I had to change oGrandTot = oSubTot5 + oSubTot3; to oGrandTot = (oSubTot5 * 1.00) + (oSubTot3 * 1.00); just to get it to use the totals as numbers.

Comment: @Aquizile: Use `parseFloat()` instead of `* 1.00` to parse the strings. It's better to write code that does what it says, than to write something where the side effect is what you are really after.